# What re the restrictions around Java EXPLICIT type conversion?

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

```
public class TypeConversion {
    Human human = new Human();
    NonHuman nonHuman = new NonHuman();
    
    public void test()
    {
        nonHuman = (NonHuman) human; //Cannot cast from Human to NonHuman
    }
}

class Human { }
class NonHuman {}
```

I was expecting the type conversion to work as its explicit, atleast at compile-time. And result in to a ClassCastException or some thing similar at run-time.

So, I am interested to know what are the restrictions around type conversion at compile time.

Comment: Something that is stored in a `Human` can NEVER be a `NonHuman`, the compiler can know that.

Answer (score 1):

Random classes cannot be typecastes/converted to each other.

Two types of conversions are usually allowed
Conversion of a sub class object into a superclass variable (Implicitely)
Conversion of a superclass object into a sub-class variable (Explicitely)

So your case would work only if the two classes had a parent child or a child parent relationship.

Comment: You can always cast to an interface type as well, even if it "seems" unrelated to the class.

Comment: yes but that would be different from what the OP is trying to achieve

Comment: @JoachimSauer, that's wonderfull to add. Thanks both. +1

Comment: @samshers you are not getting bashed, one downvote is not much - if you were to accept this answer you should have a net gain/loss of 0 reputation afaik.

Comment: I don't see any bashing